# C# HealthCheck consume api health report

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-web-api, health-check

I'm in the process of setting up some a HealthCheck in my project using the following middlewear: https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks

At the moment I have 2 projects; 1 that sends out a health report via a json object (it doesn't make use of the above middlewear) and a second project that makes use of the HealthCheck middle wear and checks my target endpoint in project 1.

My first project is a .Net Framework project that fires out the following json:

```
[{"Health":"Degraded","Description":"My Project health Check","HttpStatusCode":502}]
```

Nothing too exciting behind how that's generated:

```
    public Task<HealthCheckItemResult> GetHealthCheckAsync()
    {
        var result = new HealthCheckItemResult();
       
        result.Health = HealthState.Degraded.ToString();
        result.Status = HealthState.Degraded;
        result.Description = "health Check";
        result.HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadGateway;
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
```

However, when my Health Check project checks the endpoint, it informs me that it's Healthy, even though I've sent out a Degraded & bad gateway response.

In the Health Check project program, I have added the HealthChecksUI as follows:

```
   builder.Services.AddHealthChecksUI()
            .AddInMemoryStorage()
            .Services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddUrlGroup(new Uri("http://localhost:2401/api/health/gethealthinfo"), 
                name: "My Project",
                configureHttpMessageHandler: sp => GetHttpClientHandler())
            .Services.AddControllers();
```

The Health Check endpoints is set up as follows:

```
  app.UseEndpoints(config =>
            {
                config.MapHealthChecks("/healthz", new HealthCheckOptions
                {
                    Predicate = _ => true,
                    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
                });

                config.MapHealthChecksUI(setup =>
                {
                    setup.UIPath = "/show-health-ui"; 
                    setup.ApiPath = "/health-ui-api"; 
                    setup.PageTitle = "My wonderful Health Checks UI"; // the page title in <head>
                });

                config.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
```

When I run the Health Checker, it's always returning a 'Healthy' response even though, to me, that shouldn't be correct. The response I get from /Health-ui-api is:

```
[{"id":1,"status":"Healthy","onStateFrom":"2023-07-21T13:23:42.0433826+01:00","lastExecuted":"2023-07-21T13:25:12.4352488+01:00","uri":"/healthz","name":"Http and UI on single project with customizations-1","discoveryService":null,"entries":[{"id":1,"name":"My Project","status":"Healthy","description":null,"duration":"00:00:00.0092673","tags":[]}],"history":[]}]
```

What I was envisioning is that the HealthChecker would ping my API project, and display the results inside of the UI grid that appears. As I'm not only wanting it to tell me something is unhealthy, but why, based one what the endpoint sends out.

What is it that I'm missing that I need to do in order to have the health checker consume my api response correctly and display the correct result?